# ASP.Net How remove/ignore validation from specific elements upon submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I have an ASP.Net Core project with a simple form that has two radio buttons. One radio button has a drop-down and the other has a text-box. If the user selects the first radio button, I would like to remove/ignore the validation for the text-box (since its empty) when the user press the submit button.  Vice versa, if the user selects the second option, I would like to remove/ignore the validation from the drop-down.  I have tried a bunch of jQuery methods found on StackOverflow but none have work.

Model:

```
  public class EnrollmentModel : BaseModel
  {
    ...
    public bool PriceOption { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a rate plan")]
    public string SelectedRatePlan { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatePlans { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CustomRate { get; set; }
    ...
    }
  }
```

View:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.PriceOption, true, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "comed", @class = "col-md-1" })
      @Html.Label("Use price from current rate plans")
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedRatePlan, new SelectList(Model.RatePlans, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "rateplans", style = "width:100px;", required = "Select Rate Plan" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.SelectedRatePlan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.PriceOption, false, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "custom", @class = "col-md-1" })
      @Html.Label("Enter custom price")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.CustomRate, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "customrate", @class = "form-control", style = "width:100px;" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.CustomRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

What is rendered:

```
  div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <input checked="checked" class="col-md-1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PriceOption field is required." id="comed" name="PriceOption" type="radio" value="True" />
    <label for="Use_price_from_current_ComEd_rate">Use price from current rate plan"</label>
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a rate plan" id="rateplans" name="SelectedRatePlan" required="Select Rate Plan" style="width:100px;"><option value="">select</option>
      <option value="B70">B70</option>
      <option value="B71">B71</option>
      <option value="B90">B90</option>
      <option value="B91">B91</option>
      <option value="H70">H70</option>
      <option value="H71">H71</option>
      <option value="H90">H90</option>
      <option value="H91">H91</option>
      <option value="R70">R70</option>
      <option value="R71">R71</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="R90">R90</option>
      <option value="R91">R91</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SelectedRatePlan" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <input class="col-md-1" id="custom" name="PriceOption" type="radio" value="False" />
    <label for="Enter_custom_price">Enter custom price</label>
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field CustomRate must be a string or array type with a maximum length of &#x27;7&#x27;." data-val-maxlength-max="7" data-val-required="The CustomRate field is required." id="customrate" name="CustomRate" style="width:100px;" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CustomRate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I came across something about implementing a custom validator derived from ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator or is there easier method to achieve what I want?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expressive Annotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) is a library I've used several times in production projects. Just specify the conditions on your viewmodel and you're good to go.

So you would have something like:

```
using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes;//reference at the top

public class EnrollmentModel : BaseModel
{
    ...
    public bool PriceOption { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a rate plan")]
    public string SelectedRatePlan { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RatePlans { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("PriceOption == true")]
    public string CustomRate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it and it works well for the textbox.  However, it still wants me to select something for the drop-down.